# Can I use Copay wallet from Iran?

Tags: wallet, copay

Can I use Copay wallet from Iran? Or Iran IP is blocked? Because some wallets blocked money of Iranian users because of sanctions programs administered by the U.S. I need to know if my money will be safe in my copay wallet?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but I recommend [Electrum](https://electrum.org) instead because with Electrum you are not relying on one server for your view of the blockchain.

Copay and Electrum are both wallets that give you control of and responsibility for your private keys. Your private keys are all generated from your seed which will be displayed to you during wallet creation as 12 random English words. Only someone with knowledge of your seed will be able to move your bitcoins and since you are the only one with that knowledge only you control them. No government or corporation can freeze your bitcoins or censor your transactions.

You can find a list of other such wallets [here](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet).

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your attention. do you know about GreenAddres? is it good too?

Comment: @HosseinMN yes it's reputable however like copay you rely on one server for transaction data.

Answer (score 2):

> **I need to know if my money will be safe in my copay wallet?**

Your money is never in the wallet. The only important thing that is in a wallet is the private key.

Your money is actually in the bitcoin "Blockchain" ledger that is copied in every full bitcoin node (wallets, miners, exchanges, etc) worldwide.

So long as you have a copy of the private key in a safe place (e.g. written on paper in a locked safe), you can always regain access to your money by importing the private key into any type of wallet that supports bitcoin (BTC) or whatever similar crypto-currency you are  using.

So if you have done this, it doesn't matter if the US government shutdown Copay.

If you **don't** have your private key (or, where applicable, your recovery phrase) written down somewhere safe, and have not practised recovery, you, or your heirs, are much much more likely to lose all your money.